# Does having overloaded constructor in inheritance hierarchy signify need for composition?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

Let's say I have a user class, which has basic properties such as first name, last name, address, etc.  From this user class, I have subtypes for internal employees, consultants, and clients, all of which require extra properties, and therefore more arguments to be passed into the constructor, which would violate the Liskov Substitution Principle.  How can I compose my way out of this seemingly basic problem?

Comment: So far as I understand you're not changing the functionality by adding properties, even if you pass them through the constructor.  Here is an example: [Liskov's Substitution Principle(LSP)](http://www.oodesign.com/liskov-s-substitution-principle.html)

Comment: Well, I couldn't instantiate the different types interchangeably, so wouldn't that violate LSP?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide default values ​​for all new parameters, so that we could call the constructor without them and not get any new exceptions.

If it does not fit into the logic, different subtypes do require different properties, according to LSP, we should not use inheritance.

[Traits](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) may be used instead, for example.